# How to disable parent window while child window appear by disable closing button on parent window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have designed one window in C#(wpf) on which three buttons are there "file upload","new" and "about". when user clicked "file upload" button, the new window appear which gives information about the application. But at this time i want my parent window closing button to be disable so that when user tried to do anyting on parent window it should not allow until "upload" process will complete. Once the uploading process completed the close button will enable normally.During the process of uploading onl the button have to disable?

If anyone knows how to do this then please let me know..

Answer (score 1):

Show your upload window modally by showing it with the [`ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) method. This will effectively make your main window unavailable.

Comment: My child window appears within parent windows itself,,